# In BLiP, one schedule message works but many message at the same time does not

Tags: chatbot

Im using BLiP and i want to schedule 3 messages after 5 minutes of the last interaction with the user, one call works and others don't.

```
POST https://msging.net/commands HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Key {YOUR_TOKEN}

{  
  "id": "1",
  "to": "postmaster@scheduler.msging.net",
  "method": "set",
  "uri": "/schedules",
  "type": "application/vnd.iris.schedule+json",
  "resource": {  
    "message": {  
      "id": "ad19adf8-f5ec-4fff-8aeb-2e7ebe9f7a67",
      "to": "destination@0mn.io",
      "type": "text/plain",
      "content": "Scheduling test."
    },
    "when": "2016-07-25T17:50:00.000Z",
    "name": "New Schedule"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `id` parameter is hard-coded/constant, it will throw an exception inside BLiP's API if more than one request is sent within a short timeframe

Either change it to a randomly generated `GUID` or insert a delay between calls to fix it.